# Vintage Monopoly Game: What Year is it?

Tags: identify-this-game, monopoly, history

I have a nearly complete Monopoly set that I've been researching, and some dates I found tossed around are 1947 and 1955 (on selling pages), but I still can't even confirm the decade it was made. Here are the details of my set:

BOX:

[image: box]

Similar to this picture (taken from [here](http://monopoly.cdbpdx.com/BoxTops)) - but the border and sides are red, not white, and the bottom text is

- **PROPERTY TRADING BOARD GAME** [black text]
- Manufactured in N.Z. by [red]
- THOS. HOLDSWORTH & SONS LTD.
- LONDON & LEEDS
- Another HOLDSON Product

BOARD:

[image]

Bright green, with "TRADE MARK 711981" written below the logo

CARDS/MONEY:

[image]

Chance and Community Chest cards have rounded corners, no pictures, and the Chance cards are more pinkish than orange or red.
Money colours are: yellow ($1), light blue ($5), greyish blue ($10), green ($20), pink ($50), yellow-orange ($100), red-orange ($500).
Title Deeds: the mortgage side is red text, and my set has the error described [here](http://www.worldofmonopoly.com/errors.php) where the '1 house' rent for the last yellow property is $120 instead of $110 like the other two cards.

PIECES:
Houses/hotels are wooden, with houses being smaller and green, hotels red. Dice are plastic, red with white dots. My 6 tokens are plastic cone-like things with thin tops and round bases.

I'm sure this is enough information to come up with some possible years, I just can't find them! Thanks in advance for any input on this :)

EDIT: I can't find a copyright year anywhere but I found at the bottom of the rules it says "W. & H. LTD. - 13288"

Comment: Copyright year is often useful. At the very least, it'll provide a minimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the box looks like the images below, I'd say it's from the 1950's which is when all the mentions of a board with that trademark number appear to be dated.  I've found examples estimated at 1955 and 1957 for year of production (linked below).

[image: Monopoly Board]

http://www.cathyscollectables.co.uk/pages/Vintage_Game_Waddingtons_Monopoly_Board_Only_P_711981_Circa_1957_England_258870-z=879773&p=108919.cfm

https://www.oxfam.org.uk/shop/toys-and-games/games/john-waddinton-vintage-1955-edition-monopoly-trade-mark-711981-hd_101549207

Answer (score 1):

**1953** 
According to the reference I give below, the exact year would be 1953.

[image]

The colour of the cards, the red and white dice, the patent number 711981, and the New Zealand  provenance all indicate this.
There are more details on the site, that you have not made available to us (photos of the title deeds, playing pieces) that would allow confirmation of this date.

Reference : http://worldofmonopoly.com/albert/new_zealand.htm

Comment: That site is making a guess on the year of release "That is why I assume this set with its very special flat tokens was issued around 1953." it could be later or it could be before.